# Is there a known way to calculate the regression of composite functions?

Tags: numerical-methods, regression

Suppose you have some data which roughly follows the form $(x_n, f(g(x_n)))$, where regression models are known for $f$ and $g$ individually. Is there a known way to generate a regression model for the given dataset?

This is more of a general question, thus I have no example data. But to provide an example, suppose you have any set of data. Then say you have some function $f$:

$$f(x)=ae^{bx^2+cx+d}$$

This can be viewed as the composition of two functions:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=g(h(x))\mathrm{,\,where}\\
g(x)&=ae^x\\
h(x)&=bx^2+cx+d
\end{align}
$$

There are known methods for performing a regressions to $g$ and $h$ *individually*. My question is, since it's possible to perform a regression to $g$ and $h$ individually, are there known methods for performing a regression to $f(x)$?

Comment: Your question is not clear (for me). You said that you have some data. Wy don't you joint it to the question in order to make it more concrete.

Comment: @JJacquelin I've updated the question to hopefully make it more clear. I'm glad this question has made its way to you, since many of your answers on other question, particularly ones which reference your paper _Régressions Et Équations Intégrales_, were an inspiration for this question.

Comment: OK. One cannot definitively answer in the general case. The method cited in the referenced paper can be applied in cases where the non-linear equation model can be transformed into a linear integral equation (and/or a linear differential equation). Of course this is not always the case. So the interesting problem that you raised is much too wide. Note that the eample $g(x)=ae^x$ and $h(x)=bx^2+cx+d$ even not requires integral to linearize it. $\ln(f(x))=b\ln(a)x^2+c\ln(a)x+d\ln(a)$.